# How to use wilcox.test in R to check if sample is from a specific distribution?

Tags: r, normality-assumption, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

For example I want to check if a sample is from a normal distribution, or a different one. It this possible with wilcox.test?

Comment: @IanFellows is suggesting that you should not be testing for normality. If you dismiss that argument against what you are doing, this is not a duplicate of *how* to do it. For better or worse, [`stats::ks.test`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/ks.test.html) can be used to determine if two samples *"were drawn from the same continuous distribution"*. `ks.test(x,"pnorm")` might work. However, similar to Ian's note, `set.seed(51) ; ks.test(rnorm(100), "pnorm")` rejects the null hypothesis, suggesting that "`rnorm` is not drawn from a normal continuous distribution".

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, wilcox.test() is used for distributions of which you *know* they violate normality. To find out whether they do, use shapiro.test(). This test assumes normality. So if the p-value you obtain is < .05, you can dismiss the assumption that the data is normally distributed.

Comment: The Wilcoxon test has nothing to do with distribution testing.  It is for testing effects, e.g., shifts in distribution.  And you are confusing p-values with decision making.  p > 0.05 **does not** mean that the null hypothesis is true; it just means you did not reject $H_0$.  Absence of evidence is not evidence of absence.  And the Wilcoxon test works perfectly well if the data do come from a normal distribution (it's 0.95 efficient when compared with the $t$-test).

Comment: I'm not aware I asserted that p > .05 *means* the H0 is true; rather, quite as you say: you are not allowed to reject it and accept the H1 instead. That's what I intended to say in saying "you can dismiss the assumption that the data is normally distributed"

Comment: Yes I see that now.  But if p > 0.05 offers no conclusion the pre-test for normality is not helpful here in many cases.  More to the point, the Wilcoxon test has higher power than the t-test on the average.  Is super efficient even under normality.  So assessing normality misses the point.